# How can we put the layer in the exact column of figure as we preferred in the Sankey Diagram using network3D?

Tags: r, sankey-diagram

I am trying to use networkD3 to create a Sankey diagram and I have difficulties creating the preferred layers in the diagram.

I see that the famous example below has a wonder distinct layer, but cannot figure out how this can be produced. For example, how can we put the layer in the exact column of figure as we preferred?

[image: Example of sankey diagram]

This is the code for the example.

```
URL <- paste0('https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/',
              'master/JSONdata/energy.json')
energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)

# Plot
sankeyNetwork(Links = energy$links, Nodes = energy$nodes, Source = 'source',
              Target = 'target', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'name',
              units = 'TWh', fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.  Your code gives the example you showed; if you want something different, you should show code that doesn't work as well, and explain what is wrong with it.